# FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, fastcgi

`PHP7` `PHP-FPM`

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0
```

When

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

all works fine

Comment: where did you put cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1?

Comment: In php.ini.
Default in PHP 7.0.17 is cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1